# appcelerator dynamic forms

Tags: forms, dynamic, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i am creating a dynamic order form where you can add a new dropdown and text field into a row. I am using the XML view to create the elements but unlike jQuery, binding the same event to a class and using $('.element', parent) to access elements within a parent, you cant do this as easy with appcelerator as everything seems to use $. and an ID.

does anyone have any solutions for applying one function to multiple elements this way? i know i can bind the event easily but then the event would need to select elements within the selected object. the only way i have done this at the moment is to use a widget but that seems wrong and overkill to create a new instance for just a dropdown.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add listeners to multiple views in one call in Titanium.

Something people do a lot is adding the listener to the parent view and then use the `e.source` property to determine what actual view triggered the event. This might not work for all use cases.